# Forward GeoCoding with Skobbler api (skmaps)

Tags: ios, skmaps, clgeocoder

I am using **CLGeocoder** for forward geocoding in ios (Finding latitude and longitude using place details), but **a bit inaccurate** as per apple's documentation ([Supported Countries for CLGeocoder](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2289/_index.html)). Can anyone please let me know how it can be done using **skobbler ios api (skmaps)** accurately?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [geocoding](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec26) & [reverse geocoding](http://developer.skobbler.com/getting-started/ios#sec28) chapters in the documentation. (you also have examples of this in the demo project: nearby-search & reverse geocoding).

The only constraint: the map data has to be available on-board for the geocoding/reverse geocoding to work.